# Assign different images for different nodes in TreeView

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treeview, linq-to-xml

In my treeview I'm able to load xml data with images but this code applies a common image to all  the nodes.

How can i apply a specific image for `Parent node, sub_child node`..etc. For example, I want to assign a different image for `countries, country, name, states, state` with respect to the XML structure.

I have loaded 5 different images in the image directory. I need some example to add different images to my treeview.

```
private void populateTree()
{
    ImageList li = new ImageList();
    li.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
    li.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
    treeView1.ImageList = li;

    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + @"\images");
    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {
        li.Images.Add(file.Name, Image.FromFile(@"images\" + file.Name));
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(null, file.Name, file.Name.ToString(), file.Name.ToString());
    }

    //treeView1.ImageList = li;

    //treeView1.SelectedNode.ImageIndex = 0;
    //treeView1.SelectedNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;

    var filename = @"C:\Countries.xml";
    //First, we'll load the Xml document
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(filename);

    //Now, clear out the treeview, and add the first (root) node
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xDoc.DocumentElement.Name));
    TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
    tNode = (TreeNode)treeView1.Nodes[0];
    //Here make a call to AddNode, where we'll add all of our nodes
    addTreeNode(xDoc.DocumentElement, tNode);

    //Expand the treeview to show all nodes
    treeView1.ExpandAll();



}


private void addTreeNode(XmlNode xmlNode, TreeNode treeNode)
{
    XmlNode xNode;
    TreeNode tNode;
    XmlNodeList xNodeList;

    if (xmlNode.HasChildNodes) //The current node has children
    {
        xNodeList = xmlNode.ChildNodes;

        for (int x = 0; x <= xNodeList.Count - 1; x++) //Loop through the child nodes
        {
            xNode = xmlNode.ChildNodes[x];
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
            tNode = treeNode.Nodes[x];
            addTreeNode(xNode, tNode);
        }
    }
    else //No children, so add the outer xml (trimming off whitespace)
        treeNode.Text = xmlNode.OuterXml.Trim();
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<countries>
    <country>
        <name>India</name>
        <states>
            <state>TamilNadu</state>
            <state>Andhra</state>
            <state>Kerala</state>
            <state>Karnataka</state>
        </states>
    </country>
</countries>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're searching for [TreeNode.ImageIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.imageindex.aspx) property use.

Assign an *index* of the `Image` present in `TreeView`'s associated `ImageList`.

Comment: Could you please give me some more details on adding images. I checked that link it is for a specific array data.

Comment: @linguini: checkout [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagelist(v=vs.100).aspx) for complete example.